# Spring form validation optimization (short-circuiting)

Tags: java, spring, validation, jakarta-ee

I'm trying to optimize a Spring form validation by skipping as many database hits as possible. Here's an example validator that I have:

```
import org.springframework.validation.Errors;
import org.springframework.validation.ValidationUtils;
import org.springframework.validation.Validator;

import com.my.Car;

public class CarValidator implements Validator {
    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> c) {
        return c.equals(Car.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object car, Errors result) {
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(result, "seats", "NotEmpty.car.seats");
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(result, "colour", "NotEmpty.car.colour");

        // hitting the database here
    }

}
```

I don't want to access the database if some of the first two validations have failed. If the seats or colour fields are empty, stop processing the validation and return to the controller. But if all validations have passed, hit the db and then do the rest. Like the  short-circuit evaluation of AND in most languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surround your db call with a check for the number of errors found:

```
if (result.getErrorCount() == 0) {
    //do the DB checks
}
```